# Vuex Store value is changing while updating the reference

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am setting the store value to a variable using getters and when I later change the variable value, vuex store value is getting updated.

Below given is my code

```
let startdate = this.$store.getters.getDateRange.start
let endDate = this.$store.getters.getDateRange.end

let compareStart = startdate
compareStart.setDate(startdate.getDate() - 7)
let compareEnd = endDate
compareEnd.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7)
```

While setDate function is executed, the store value is changed to 'compareEnd' value.
Why is this happening?

Is this because it's an object reference? If so what is the work around?

Comment: For time being i solved the issue :

Answer (score 0):

For time being i solved the issue. I was passing an object from the store and hence was updating the value. So i changed the code a little bit.

```
    let startdate = this.$store.getters.getDateRange.start
    let endDate = this.$store.getters.getDateRange.end     
    let compareStart = new Date(startdate.getUTCFullYear(), startdate.getUTCMonth(), startdate.getUTCDate())
compareStart.setDate(startdate.getDate() - 7)
    let compareEnd = new Date(endDate.getUTCFullYear(), endDate.getUTCMonth(), endDate.getUTCDate())
compareEnd.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7)
```

I'm not sure is this the best way or not.

Answer (score -1):

Great Question! This is a classic Javascript case of Pass by Reference and Pass by Value.

In your case the startDate/endDate becomes a reference of this.$store.getters.getDateRange.start / end and thus whenever you update the startDate/endDate it changes the one at the store.

Looks to me your store variable is a JS date object. Try the following.

```
//Let's Breakdown References

let startdate = new Date(this.$store.getters.getDateRange.start.valueOf())
let endDate = new Date(this.$store.getters.getDateRange.end.valueOf())
```

Learn More about JS variables Here [https://hackernoon.com/javascript-reference-and-copy-variables-b0103074fdf0]